# Django rest framwork, разбор JSON

Tags: python, django, json, django-rest-framework

Есть модель в django файл `models.py`:

```py
class RawTransactionSale(models.Model):
    summ = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
    sign = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    payments = models.JSONField(blank=False)
    merchant = models.JSONField(blank=False)


class PaymentTable(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    PaymentID = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, blank=False)
    paymentAmount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
    raw_transaction_sale = models.ForeignKey('RawTransactionSale', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='raw_transaction_sale')


class MerchantTable(models.Model):
    merchantName = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    merchantID = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, blank=False)
    payment = models.ForeignKey('PaymentTable', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='merchant')
```

Есть сериализаторы - файл `serializers.py`:

```py
class PaymentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PaymentTable
        fields = '__all__'

class MerchantSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MerchantTable
        fields = '__all__'

        
class RawTransactionSaleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = RawTransactionSale
        fields = '__all__'
```

Есть `viewset` - файл `views.py`:

```
class RawTransactionSaleViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = RawTransactionSale.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RawTransactionSaleSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = RawTransactionSaleSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        validated_data = serializer.validated_data
        payments_data = validated_data.pop('payments')
        merchant_data = validated_data.pop('merchant')
        merchant_serializer = MerchantSerializer(data=merchant_data)
        merchant_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        merchant = merchant_serializer.save()
        raw_transaction_sale = RawTransactionSale.objects.create(merchant=merchant, **validated_data)
        for payment_data in payments_data:
            payment_data['raw_transaction_sale'] = raw_transaction_sale.id
            payment_serializer = PaymentSerializer(data=payment_data)
            payment_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            PaymentTable.objects.create(raw_transaction_sale=raw_transaction_sale, **payment_serializer.validated_data)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(raw_transaction_sale)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

На API приходит такой JSON по транзакции:

```py
{
    "summ": 1860.0,                                         
    "sign": "123456677531",
    "SaleMerchID": "ca9f9c0d-c2d0-321d-8b9a-123c3fc5b543",                  
    "merchant" : {
        "merchantName": "SuperShop",                            
        "merchantID" : "12345678-1234-abcd-dcab-123abc456def",                                              
        },
        
    "payments": [                                               
        {                                                       
            "date": "2023-04-27T15:50:15.000+0400",             
            "PaymentID": "4dba1234-f19e-1234-a432-ca5d15f9ec21",        
            "paymentAmount": 1860,                                                                      
        }
    ],
}
```

Пытаюсь из набора данных JSON сохранить payments в отдельную таблицу `PaymentTable`, `merchant` в таблицу `MerchantTable`, связать с данной транзакцией и таблицу `PaymentTable` привязать к таблице `MerchantTable`, но получаю ошибку `"{"payment":["Обязательное поле."]}"`. Где я ошибся?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `data` вам приходит `merchant` без поля `payment`:

```json
"merchant" : 
{
   "merchantName": "SuperShop",                            
   "merchantID" : "12345678-1234-abcd-dcab-123abc456def",                                              
},
```

Затем в методе `create` вы передаете в сериализатор данные без этого поля и когда происходит проверка `merchant_serializer.is_valid` рейзится ошибка.

```py
merchant_data = validated_data.pop('merchant')
merchant_serializer = MerchantSerializer(data=merchant_data)
merchant_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
merchant = merchant_serializer.save()
```

Либо задайте полю `payment` - `default`, либо создайте сначала `instance` - `payment-a` и передавайте его вместе с датой в `MerchantSerializer` и вообще если у вас `payments` это список, то связь `ForeignKey` вам не подходит и нужно создать `ManyToMany`.

Comment: Действительно, я пытаюсь создать инстанс **merchant**, а **payment** еще нет.  Задумался... А подскажите чайнику, как **создайте сначала instance - payment-a и передавайте его вместе с датой в MerchantSerializer** вот это сделать, что-то не соображу...

Comment: В том виде, который сейчас у вас, я не вижу, как это можно реализовать. Потому что у вас много платежей, а в таблице поле `payment` ссылается на один. Либо вы принимаете один платеж и используете вложенный сериализатор для этого платежа. Либо меняете на связь `manytomany`, [здесь](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#serializer-relations) вы должны найти ответы.